# Visual Studio @ symbol prefix in debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

When starring at the debugger for my C# project, I discover that Visual Studio 2019 is putting an extra '@' prefix symbol in front of my member variable (struct). What does this means ?

[image]

For reference, my simple struct (JSON deserialization):

```
public struct Attribute
{
    public string keyword { get; init; }
    public string[] path { get; init; }
    public string type { get; init; }
}
```

---

Per suggestion in the comments below, I did report an issue using my corporate account. I'll update this SO post, once I receive the bug number.

Comment: I doubt it's duplicate of that question, because "type" is not a reserved keyword.

Comment: @ is used to turn escape a language keyword into a plain identifier name.  "type" is not a keyword in C#, but it is in VB.NET.  The managed debugger engine handles both languages, the probable reason it shows up here.  Also happens for example when you debug a VB.NET program, looking at an object with a name like "yield", gets escaped to [yield].  Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to let them know about it.

Comment: Besides, if you do report this problem, remember to share the question link here, other forum members can go to vote for it, and follow up that thread to see the latest fix/information.